# generate c++ code from state machine model yakindu

Tags: code-generation, state-machine

i tried to generate code from some state machine model made in eclipse yakindu plugin. everywhere it is advertised that yakindu can generate c++ code but i only found the option to generate C and Java.

Does anybody has an hint for me?

Answer (score 2):

the C++ Code Generator will be part of the next release planned for end of May. If you do not want to wait for the next release and are familiar with eclipse plugins you can check out the sourcecode for the c++ code generator from

https://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/yakindu/SCT2/trunk/plugins
org.yakindu.sct.generator.cpp

and export it as plugin.

Otherwise you can download the new release at the end of this month from http://www.statecharts.org

Comment: iam not that used to eclipse and java. that does "and export it as plugin." mean?

Comment: if you checked out the plugin to your eclipse workspace and the plugins is compile error free, you can right click on the project and select export / deployable plugins and features from the context menu. Then you can copy the exported jar to the plugin folder of your SCT Eclipse.

Comment: This comment is already 2 years old. And by the way: It is an open source project I am committer at and free of charge. So this is not a product advertisement.

Comment: The age is irrelevant; the answer is still here. If it does no longer apply, you should delete it. As to self-promotion, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior. It doesn't matter if the product is free or open source, you must disclose your affiliation. Must. Not should.